# Fixed Navbar disappears when adding filter blur

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to add a blurred background for Bootstrap 4 modals.

My idea was, to put everything on the site in one container (navbar, content and footer), which I then add `filter:blur(4px)` to, when body.modal-open is set.

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work with a fixed navbar - when you are scrolled halfway into the page and open a modal, the navbar simply disappears.

Anyone can explain why/knows how to fix this?

HTML:

```
<div id="content-container">
    <nav class="navbar fixed-top">
        <!--some nav elements -->
    </nav>
    <main>
        <!-- content goes here -->
    </main>
    <footer>
        <!-- some footer -->
    </footer>
<div>
<div id="modal-container">
    <!-- Modals go here -->
<div>
```

CSS:

```
body.modal-open #content-container{
    filter: blur(4px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
    -moz-filter: blur(4px);
    -o-filter: blur(4px);
    -ms-filter: blur(4px);
}
```

Sample on codepen:
https://codepen.io/danmoreng/pen/WVpzOm

Comment: Just FYI - filter:blur compatibility is very poor with edge & IE so we careful. https://caniuse.com/#search=filter%3Ablur

Comment: Yeah also found that out. But doesn't seem to matter that much, it simply isn't blurred then - I still keep the backdrop element.

Comment: Interestingly, I got inspired by the modals when you download the Edge Insider Demo - and their blur effect even works in todays Edge: https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download

Comment: @Danmoreng Please check below answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I have done some changes according to the requirement please check.

[`Blur body on modal`](https://codepen.io/creativesingh/pen/XvMBJW)

Comment: Actually navbar just got blurred with other content. It is not disappearing, I just add blur to everything except navbar. Let me know if i can help any other way. Thanks